# Python não acha o membro "wait_read" em "Gevent.socket"

Tags: python, socket

```
import gevent

from gevent import socket

from gevent.pool import Pool

from gevent.event import Event

.

.

.

def __receive__(self):

        """ 
        receive response packets 
        """
        while not self.die_event.is_set():
            # wait till we can recv
            try:
                socket.wait_read(self.socket.fileno())
            except socket.error, (errno,msg):
                if errno == socket.EBADF:
                    print "interrupting wait_read"
                    return
                # reraise original exceptions
                print "re-throwing socket exception on wait_read()"
                raise
```

> Error: [E1101]187: GPing.*receive*:Module 'socket' has no 'wait_read'
>   member

Comment: Você não está redefinindo o nome `socket` em algum lugar do código, está?

Comment: Seria isso aqui:  'self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, icmp)' ?